# iframe + asp.net + iPad Issue

Tags: php, asp.net, ios, ipad, iframe

I display this tracking page on our ecommerce site:
http://parcels-uk.tntpost.com/mytrackandtrace/trackandtrace.aspx?lang=en&D=us&B=RR106765194NL

I show this using an iFrame in a php page on our own domain.

The problem is that most of the time the tracking links won't work on an iPad.  I believe this is the issue:
http://blog.lavablast.com/post/2011/05/29/Gotcha-iPad-versus-ASPNET.aspx

The problem is I can't add code to the application as I am just displaying this in an iFrame.

Does anyone know how I could get around this issue?  Would adding anything to the php page solve it?

(I have already tried contacting the courier company to let them know about the issue but they don't seem interested in trying to fix it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think that "adding anything" would help you to resolve this issue. iFrames sometimes becaome a problem in certain ways.
What you could do is: build some that reads the content of your tnt site and then inject the result as a div into the DOM of your main/displaying page.